# Save textview attributes when orientation changed

Tags: android, landscape

I need to save the textview attributes such as text,color,background color, padding values in `onSaveInstanceState()` -

The textview `time` is in `bindView()` in Adapter class -

```
viewHolder.time.setText(strText);
viewHolder.time.setTextColor(0xff000000);
viewHolder.time.setTextSize(17);
viewHolder.time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
viewHolder.time.setBackgroundColor(nColor);
viewHolder.time.setPadding(25,25,25,25);
```

How do I save them in `onSaveInstanceState()` and use it in `onCreate()` when orientation changed to landscape.

I dont want to use `android:configChanges` since I have different layout for landscape.

**EDIT** :

In MyAdapter.java,

```
@Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        Child child = children.createStopFromCursor(cursor);
        MyFragment ndf = new MyFragment();   
                    viewHolder.time.setText(strText);
                    viewHolder.time.setTextColor(0xff000000);
                    viewHolder.time.setTextSize(17);
                    viewHolder.time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewHolder.time.setBackgroundColor(nColor);
                    viewHolder.time.setPadding(25,25,25,25);
                    ndf.setLandScape(strText,0xff000000,17,nColor);
                    view.invalidate();
        }
    }
```

In MyFragment.java,

```
public void setLandScape(String time,int time_color,int time_size,int time_Bcolor){
        this.delay_time = time;
        this.delay_time_color = time_color;
        this.delay_time_size = time_size;
        this.delay_time_BColor = time_Bcolor;
      }

@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        int[] padding = {25,25,25,25};
        TextViewLandscape attributes = new TextViewLandscape(delay_time, delay_time_color, delay_time_size, delay_time_BColor, padding);
        ArrayList<TextViewLandscape> list = new ArrayList<TextViewLandscape>();
        list.add(attributes);
        outState.putParcelableArrayList("keyTextViewAttributes", list);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
            TextViewLandscape textViewAttributes = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("keyTextViewAttributes");
        }}
```

In TextViewLandscape.java,

```
public class TextViewLandscape implements Parcelable {
    private String text;
    private int textColor;
    private int textSize;
    private int backgroundColor;
    private int[] paddingAttrs = {4};

    public TextViewLandscape(String text, int textColor, int textSize, int backgroundColor, int[] paddingAttrs) {
        this.text = text;
        this.textColor = textColor;
        this.textSize = textSize;
        this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
        this.paddingAttrs = paddingAttrs;
    }

    public TextViewLandscape(Parcel in) {
        text = in.readString();
        textColor = in.readInt();
        textSize = in.readInt();
        backgroundColor = in.readInt();
        paddingAttrs = in.createIntArray();
    }

    public static final Creator<TextViewLandscape> CREATOR = new Creator<TextViewLandscape>() {
        @Override
        public TextViewLandscape createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new TextViewLandscape(in);
        }

        @Override
        public TextViewLandscape[] newArray(int size) {
            return new TextViewLandscape[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(text);
        dest.writeInt(textColor);
        dest.writeInt(textSize);
        dest.writeInt(backgroundColor);
        dest.writeIntArray(paddingAttrs);
    }
}
```

Still not working in Landscape mode....

Comment: Why don't you save them in object you are binding to? Don't they depend on some property, like boolean isFavorited for example?

Comment: the adapter will be reloaded upon onCreate() so the list will be populated again, how are you maintaining this? use the same to save the attributes of the highlighted (selected) textView

Comment: @F.sh How do I do this?

Comment: See my updated answer, in `onCreate` just change `TextViewLandscape textViewAttributes = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("keyTextViewAttributes")` to  `ArrayList<TextViewLandscape> textViewAttributes = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayListExtra("keyTextViewAttributes")`

Comment: I am not able to use getParcelableArrayListExtra. It says cannot resolve method

Comment: And what does happen if you use `getParcelableArrayList`?

Comment: How do you mean not working, what is the value of `textViewAttributes` in your `onCreate` callback?

Comment: The value of textViewAttributes is [com.example.children.fragments.TextViewLandscape@5da00cf]. This value comes only when phone turned to landscape mode and again when turned back to portrait mode, I have a new value

Answer (score 1):

In that case, you will have to define some Parcelable class which keeps all your `TextView` attributes, for instance:

```
 public class TextViewAttributes implements Parcelable {
    private String text;
    private int textColor;
    private int textSize;
    private int visibility;
    private int backgroundColor;
    private int[] paddingAttrs = {4};

    public TextViewAttributes(String text, int textColor, int textSize, int visibility, int backgroundColor, int[] paddingAttrs) {
        this.text = text;
        this.textColor = textColor;
        this.textSize = textSize;
        this.visibility = visibility;
        this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
        this.paddingAttrs = paddingAttrs;
    }

    public TextViewAttributes(Parcel in) {
        text = in.readString();
        textColor = in.readInt();
        textSize = in.readInt();
        visibility = in.readInt();
        backgroundColor = in.readInt();
        paddingAttrs = in.createIntArray();
    }

    public static final Creator<TextViewAttributes> CREATOR = new Creator<TextViewAttributes>() {
        @Override
        public TextViewAttributes createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new TextViewAttributes(in);
        }

        @Override
        public TextViewAttributes[] newArray(int size) {
            return new TextViewAttributes[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(text);
        dest.writeInt(textColor);
        dest.writeInt(textSize);
        dest.writeInt(visibility);
        dest.writeInt(backgroundColor);
        dest.writeIntArray(paddingAttrs);
    }
}
```

This is how you save the values:

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        int[] padding = {0,5,1,3};
        TextViewAttributes attributes = new TextViewAttributes("message", 4, 5, 7, 1, padding);
        ArrayList<TextViewAttributes> list = new ArrayList<TextViewAttributes>();
        list.add(attributes);
        outState.putParcelableArrayList("keyTextViewAttributes", list);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

And this is how you retrieve them in `onCreate` method:

```
 if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            ArrayList<TextViewAttributes> textViewAttributes = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayListExtra("keyTextViewAttributes");
        }
```

Comment: You will have to create callback from your Fragment to your activity, check out this [example](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Comment: Why do I need the Parcel variable 'dest' since in onSaveInstanceState() I am not using it

Comment: I implemented all 3 parts which you have given above...Still it is not working

Comment: Sorry, I made a little mistake, in `onCreate` instead of `savedInstanceState.getParcelable("keyTextViewAttributes")` call `savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayListExtra("keyTextViewAttributes")`. Does it work now?

Comment: Still no result... Shall I post what I am doing?

Comment: I updated my answer, check the last code snippet. Try to put breakpoint at the `textViewAttributes`  in `onCreate` method and see what you get

Comment: Ok...Please see my edited code..What I am doing is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `configChanges` in `activity` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` as gien below:

```
<activity
    android:name=".TextureViewActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
```

Comment: I have different layout for landscape

Answer (score 0):

Everything can be saved without a problem in **onSaveInstaceState()**. The drawback is you will have to use lots of keys for the values and at some point it can become confusing.

Restore them in **onCreateView()** by checking if the **savedInstanceState** is not **NULL** and by using the same keys I had used previously.

**EDIT:**
In fact you don't really need to save these values. When the screen orientation is changed, the fragment which contains the adapter will be recreated and the adapter as well. But you have your values hard coded in the adapter. Thus, you don't need to save them.

Comment: Ok... What are the keys that I could use for visibility and Padding and it is in Adapter class. How do I get it in Fragment class

Comment: @Mark023 check the new **EDIT**

Comment: If i dont need to save them, then why after screen orientation the values i dont get the values.

Comment: When you pass through the adapter again you have your values for **textColor, textSize, visibility, padding** already hardcoded. I can assume that you get **strText** from a data set of Strings or something like that. You need to save that data set from your fragment and not trying to save the properties of your TextView, because you already have them.